# flutter_branch_sdk generated deep links do not open app on iOS, generated link always takes to AppStore

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking, branch.io

I have been trying to use Branch SDK to implement deep linking into our iOS application. The Branch URL redirects directly to App Store and never attempts to open the application. I must be missing something.
This works as expected on Android though.

What I've done:

Added branch_key to application plist
Added URL Scheme to URL Types in the Info.plist
Enabled Associated Domains in both the project and the App ID in the developer console.

Enabled all iOS deep linking settings on Branch Dashboard, set the Bundle Identifier & Apple App Prefix both correctly.

I'm copying the link generated from app pasting it on any other app and on clicking the link, Safari opens and shows go to app, then App Store is opened as if the application is not installed.

Am I missing a configuration step or what could be possible reasons for this to work like this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same boat right now.

Comment: For me, it ended up being that I needed "applinks:" in front of each of my associated domain entries in the "Signing & Capabilities" tab in xcode. Now it opens the app first and then the app store, but app is opening with data so close enough I guess.